# Pairwise swap elements of a given linked list by changing links

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list

[GeeksForGeeks challenge](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pairwise-swap-elements-of-a-given-linked-list-by-changing-links/):

> Given a singly linked list, write a function to swap nodes pairwise.
>
> **For example** :
>
> if the linked list is 1->2->3->4->5->6->7 then the function should
>   change it to 2->1->4->3->6->5->7, and if the linked list is
>   1->2->3->4->5->6 then the function should change it to
>   2->1->4->3->6->5

```
#include <iostream>

// structure of a Node in the linked list
struct Node {
    int data;
    Node *next;
};

// append data to end of linked list
Node *append(Node *head, int data) {
    auto newNode = new Node{data, nullptr};
    if (head == nullptr)
        return newNode;

    auto temp{head};
    while (temp->next)
        temp = temp->next;
    temp->next = newNode;

    return head;
}

//  display the list

void display(Node *head) {
    std::cout << "The list : \t";
    while (head != nullptr) {
        std::cout << head->data << " ";
        head = head->next;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl ;
}

//  pairwise swap of the elements in the given linked lists
void pairwiseSwap(Node **head_ref) {

    if(((*head_ref) == nullptr) || ((*head_ref)->next == nullptr))
        return ;

    Node *temp1 = nullptr, *temp2 = nullptr ;
    Node *prev = nullptr, *curr =(*head_ref) ;

    while(curr != nullptr) {

        //  temp1 : first element of the pair
        //  temp2 : second element of the pair
        temp1 = curr;
        temp2 = curr->next;

        //  if the the 2nd element in the pair is nullptr, then exit the loop
        if(temp2 == nullptr){
            break ;
        }
//      curr = curr->next->next ;

        //  if the current element is head, then previous one must be nullptr
        //  In either case swapping the nodes
        if(prev == nullptr){
            prev = temp1;
            temp1->next = temp2->next;
            temp2->next = temp1;
            (*head_ref) = temp2 ;
        }
        else {      
            temp1->next = temp2->next;
            temp2->next = temp1;
            prev->next = temp2;
            prev = temp1;
        }

        //  moving to the next pair of nodes
        curr = temp1->next ;
    }
}

//  Driver function
int main() {
    Node *a = nullptr ;

    // for odd number of nodes
    a = append(a, 15); 
    a = append(a, 10); 
    a = append(a, 5);  
    a = append(a, 20); 
    a = append(a, 3); 
//  a = append(a, 2);

    pairwiseSwap(&a);

    display(a);

   // for even number of nodes
    a = append(a, 15); 
    a = append(a, 10); 
    a = append(a, 5);  
    a = append(a, 20); 
    a = append(a, 3); 
    a = append(a, 2);

    pairwiseSwap(&a);

    display(a);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's weird that you picked `append` as your primitive for building test cases, when `prepend` would be so much simpler and faster — `O(1)` instead of `O(n)`.

---

```
auto newNode = new Node{data, nullptr};
```

This is a very "modern" way of writing what would be more idiomatically written as

```
Node *newNode = new Node(data, nullptr);
```

I would weakly recommend the latter. And I would *strongly* recommend, if you do nothing else, at least calling out explicitly when you're working with raw (non-owning) pointers:

```
auto *newNode = new Node{data, nullptr};  // the asterisk means watch out!
```

---

```
auto temp{head};
```

Again, I'd write simply

```
Node *temp = head;
```

or at least

```
auto *temp = head;
```

The `*` signals the reader to watch out for pointer pitfalls (aliasing, memory leaks); the `=` signals the reader that an initialization is happening here. You might be surprised how easy it is to glance over `auto temp{head};` surrounded by other lines of code and not even recognize that it's *introducing the name `temp`!*

---

```
//  pairwise swap of the elements in the given linked lists
void pairwiseSwap(Node **head_ref) {
```

Some coding guidelines tell you to pass the inout parameter `head_ref` by pointer here, instead of by reference. I'm going to assume you're following one of those guidelines.

---

```
return ;
```

is an unidiomatic whitespace style; most programmers would write

```
return;
```

You actually put an extra space before a *lot* of semicolons in this function (but not consistently). Are you French? ;)

---

You should definitely factor out the "swap two nodes" functionality into a named function. I somewhat suspect that this would do, but you'd have to draw it out on paper...

```
void swap_two_nodes(Node *&p, Node *&q) {
    assert(p->next == q);
    std::swap(p, q);
}
```

Alternatively — and since I've confused myself ;) — you could just write a recursive version of the whole thing:

```
Node *pairwise_swap(Node *head) {
    if (head && head->next) {
        Node *first = head->next;
        Node *second = head;
        Node *tail = pairwise_swap(head->next->next);
        head = first;
        first->next = second;
        second->next = tail;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Turning this into tail-recursion is left as an (easy) exercise for the reader.

---

```
// for even number of nodes
a = append(a, 15);
```

Appending an even number of nodes to an odd-length list does *not* result in an even-length list. Did you try *running* your test code? Did you look at the output and verify that it was correct? You should have!

Answer (score 2):

Looking at just your `pairwiseSwap()` function… there are too many special cases.

Every iteration through the loop should verify that there are at least two more elements to process.  You shouldn't need a special case to check for `if(((*head_ref) == nullptr) || ((*head_ref)->next == nullptr)) return ;` to start.

On the other hand, the loop condition should make it clear that at least two nodes are required to proceed.  You've obfuscated the check for the second node as `if(temp2 == nullptr) { break ; }`.

You then have a special case for the first iteration (`//  if the current element is head, then previous one must be nullptr`).  That special case would be better handled by introducing a `preHead` object, whose `next` points to the original head node.

After eliminating the special cases as described above, and renaming `temp1` → `a` and `temp2` → `b` (because "temp" is nearly always meaningless in a variable name), we get this simple solution:

```
void pairwiseSwap(Node **head) {
    Node preHead{0, *head};
    for (Node *prev = &preHead, *a, *b; (a = prev->next) && (b = a->next); prev = a) {
        a->next = b->next;
        b->next = a;
        prev->next = b;
    }
    *head = preHead.next;
}
```